# Case sensitive string comparison Image J Macro

Tags: macros, comparison, case-sensitive, imagej

String comparisons are case insensitive using Image J Macro.  For example, the following will print "True":

```bs
if ("c" == "C") {
    print("True");
}
```

Does anyone know of a workaround to make case-sensitive comparisons in image J macro?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Javascript from within the macro:

```bs
eval("script", "'c'=='C'");
```

or resort right away to a full-fledged [scripting language](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_Help) like Javascript, Beanshell, Python, etc...